# Remove button and just prompt for input?

Tags: javascript, button

So i have this code here. How would I remove the button so when you click the html file it automatically asks for input? I'm really new to this so i understand most of whats happening here but i'm a bit lost.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MAN I'M A FAILURE</title>
<div><button id="create-table">Create table</button></div>
<div>
  <table id="table-root"></table>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
th, td {
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    var button = document.querySelector('#create-table');
    var tableRoot = document.querySelector('#table-root');

    var movies = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    var properties = ['Title', 'studio', 'Revenue'];

button.addEventListener('click', e => {
  tableRoot.innerHTML = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++ ) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    for (let j = 0; j < properties.length; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var response = window.prompt(`Please enter the ${properties[j].toLowerCase()} of movie ${movies[i]}`);

      td.innerText = response;
      if (response === null || response === '') td.innerText = `${properties[j]} not supplied`;

      tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    tableRoot.appendChild(tr);
  }
});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply remove the event listener like this and the button and directly run the code which was first triggered in the case of a click. Like this:

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#create-table');
    var tableRoot = document.querySelector('#table-root');

    var movies = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    var properties = ['Title', 'studio', 'Revenue'];


  tableRoot.innerHTML = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < movies.length; i++ ) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    for (let j = 0; j < properties.length; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    var response = window.prompt(`Please enter the ${properties[j].toLowerCase()} of movie ${movies[i]}`);

      td.innerText = response;
      if (response === null || response === '') td.innerText = `${properties[j]} not supplied`;

      tr.appendChild(td);
    }

    tableRoot.appendChild(tr);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div>
  <table id="table-root"></table>
</div>
```

Now the javascript gets directly executed and does not have to wait on the event from the click.

Hopefully this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m reading your question correctly, you’re looking to have the page ask for the user input when the page loads, vs waiting for the user to click the button. All you have to do is add an event listener to the ‘DOMContentLoaded’ event for the document, rather than a ‘click’ event on the button (which is what you have now).  [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) should help.